# PC Super Sluggish After Installing New Graphics Card

Tags: graphics-card, performance, gpu

After installing my GT 610 my PC has been slowed down drastically. For example it takes 3 minutes to open chrome and 40 seconds to open the menu when right clicking on the desktop. GPU-Z says the the load on my GPU is only 1%. Games run fine though with the GT 610.

Specs:

```
Intel Core 2 Duo  E7500 @ 2.93Ghz CPU
GT 610 GPU
2GB DDR2 667Mhz RAM
MSI G31TM-P35 Motherboard
WD Caviar Blue 250GB & 320GB HDD
350W PSU
```

Comment: I dig the username. I haven't got much to go on except looking solely at the system specs, but "recently added X" and "350W PSU" shouts "insufficient power".

Comment: If you take it out and go back to your previous graphics adapter, does the speed return to normal?

Comment: The GT610 only draws 30 watts. While it's possible power is the issue, it doesn't seem particularly likely.

Comment: The PC was fine before the New GPU, I uninstalled the GPU, but the PC. remains a potato. a driver isssue?

Comment: I would not expect it to be a driver issue if the GPU was removed from the system.  If you are getting display from the on-board card it shouldn't be looking at the driver for the 610

Comment: ok... but its gotta be some of the gt 610 software like geforce experience

Answer (score 0):

Definitely try swapping the graphics card back out like Techie007 said and you could use the Newegg PSU calculator with that setup as well and see what your power draw is with that card.

[Newegg PSU Calculator](http://images10.newegg.com/BizIntell/tool/psucalc/index.html?name=Power-Supply-Wattage-Calculator&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleKWLess&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleKWLess-_-DSA-_-CategoryPages-_-NA&gclid=CKzP5NmU4s0CFQQQaQodGrUGcA&gclsrc=aw.ds) recommends a 377W power supply for your setup.  It's recommended that your components, at peak draw, use (IIRC)60-70% of your power supply's max wattage.  I'm not sure if Newegg's calculator takes this into consideration but as jatuttle0 said, it looks like insufficient power.